# very impressed-->dead impressed (adjective)

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Instead of using "very", which is annoyingly too common, would it not sound awkward if I use "dead"+adjective:

> My friends would be **dead impressed** if they saw me wearing the latest Prada bag that cost 1.2 billion dollars!

I am no native English speaker and I am sure if this is valid because when I google the word combination, nothing appeared.

Comment: [would it sound awkward: would not will] impressed to death, not dead impressed.

Comment: @JohnArvin why isn't "My friends would be impressed..." adequate? You avoided the over-use of "very".

Comment: @WeatherVane, I'm trying to **intensify my wordings** simply because I need it for an English exam and want it, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I would use with caution. Its not really proper English but is used quite commonly among the less well spoken population.

It is becoming more common, but (in my opinion) should not used as an adverb at all.

I'm not sure why you couldn't find it on google. I tried "dead as an adverb" and there were plenty of results. E.g. [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dead_3)

Note that the first definition is *completely*, which does sit better with me than *very*.

Comment: Have you? Please send me the link here if you have, it should be "dead impressed" **in combination.**

Comment: @john, not in combination, there is no need for that. Please see the link I have provided on my answer

Answer (score 2):

I gather you're extrapolating from the use of "dead" as an intensifier in other expressions such as ["dead certain"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+certain) or ["dead on"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+on) (as well as "dead right", "dead on time", etc.) where "dead" means "absolutely" or "perfectly".  In English as in any language, you *can* apply the idiomatic use to a new context, but you may confuse your audience.

I would understand what you meant by "dead impressed", especially if spoken with positive intonation, but I would assume it was slang from somewhere other than where I'm from.  A similar example is the Boston (US) use of "wicked", as in:

> [My boy's **wicked** smart](https://youtu.be/hIdsjNGCGz4?t=212)

Given the previous dialogue from the linked movie, it's obvious even to someone not from Boston that "wicked" means "extraordinarily".  In the same way your use of "dead" is fine, but it depends on the context.

Note: You may not find examples of "dead impressed" as an idiom, but instead try "dead sexy" and there will be many.

Comment: I don't think it's really a matter of "extrapolating" ***dead impressed*** from related usages such as ***dead certain, dead centre, dead right***. To my mind, they really are just *the same* usage - it's just that ***all*** such "intensifier" usages are considered to be somewhat "colloquial, slangy" today (but I don't think this was always the case, and I doubt there was ever a time when ***He's dead serious*** was seen as a "colloquial" alternative to ***He's deadly serious***).

Comment: It really does not work at all. Why not just say so? impressed to death, you didn't even mention.

Comment: But why not use "really"?

Comment: @AIQ  You can, but it doesn't sound the same as a *properly* used slang expression.  Slang is much the same in any language -- it adds subtle nuance,   identifies the speaker's origin, culture, and possibly social status, and often sounds more interesting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Right, I knew I heard "dead" used as an intensifier in many contexts, but I couldn't recall specific examples.  Or perhaps I just blocked out *"I'm **dead sexy**!"* from the movie *Austin Powers 2*.

Comment: @Andrew Oh I see. Then "crazy" works too.

Comment: @AIQ, using "really" is a lousy, lazy intensifier also.

Comment: @Andrew: I think there's definitely something here to do with whether the context is one where ***dead*** could more naturally be replaced with ***exactly*** or with ***very***. My gut feel is that *in general* it feels more like a modern slangy usage in the second case. But when I try to think of specific examples, I come up with as many that seem to contradict that principle as support it.

Comment: @AIQ: I think non-native speakers in particular should be *extremely* careful about using ***crazy*** as an alternative intensifier to ***very***. It's crazy optimistic to hope it'll work in every context, and I doubt there are any simple "rules" to define where the usage does or doesn't work (but I'd say it's almost always *colloquial* even when it does "work", and colloquialisms aren't appropriate for all contexts anyway).

Comment: The use of 'dead' as an intensifier in informal speech was very common where I grew up in London in the 1950s. We all used to laugh at the warning notice outside the local bus garage that warned (without punctuation) 'Dead Slow Buses Turning'. if it is being used again then it is a case of what goes around comes around.